# Camera not working on actual device

Tags: android, android-camera

I've integrated Camera within my app. The below codes are working fine when I'm running on emulator and I've selected webcam as my camera in ADB. But when I'm running on Actual device like Nexus 7 then my app is not able to detect camera. camera is working fine in this tablet independently but not within my app.

CameraActivity.java

```
 //I've imported hardware camera class
   import android.hardware.Camera;
   import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;

  // Some activity code
    if (!getPackageManager().
      hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) { // Issue is coming from here. 
      Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    } else {
      cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
      if (cameraId < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
      }
    }
```

Mainfest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
  </uses-permission>

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes here

try to check:

> hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)

Instead:

> hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)

Nexus 7 having only front-facing camera.

Android camera selection algorithm defaults to the rear camera.